# Vimeo video embed in Shopify CORS issue: There was an error fetching the embed code from Vimeo

Tags: firefox, cors, shopify, embed, vimeo

I am completely stuck with this. I've googled everything I can think of and can't solve this problem. Here's what happened:

I have a Shopify theme that lets me embed a Vimeo video which auto-plays on the homepage. It was working great. I wanted to hide the Vimeo player controls and so I added a new CSS file to my shopify theme and added one line of code:

```
#div-id {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

To prevent the controls from showing up when I moused over the containing div. I saved the theme and all the sudden the auto-playing video was broken on FireFox (the change worked in Chrome and Safari). I got the following errors:

```
CORS request did not succeed
Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing
There was an error fetching the embed code from Vimeo
```

[image]

I figured maybe because you need a pro account on Vimeo to hide embedded video controls, my CSS was violating their agreement and they blocked the video. Simple enough, I deleted the CSS file and saved the theme exactly how it was before I touched it. But the video won't load still. And the kicker is, it is only broken for me, and only in FireFox.

I've cleared my entire browser cache, cookies, local data, and history. I've tried in private browsing mode. I uninstalled and reinstalled FireFox, etc. Even if I preview previous older theme copies that were never touched with this change, it still shows this error.

At this point I don't know what to do or what to Google.

Comment: It's definitely not about CSS. Could you please provide a link to the page with the video and also a Firefox version?

Comment: www.littlesycamore.com
Firefox: 74.0 (64-bit) macOS Catalina. 

I can confirm this problem isn't happening for anyone except me. Chatted with Shopify tech support and they couldn't replicate it.

Comment: It's the auto-playing video about half way down the page.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what was wrong?

Comment: No not yet, still working on it